# How to get numbers each side of a symbol

Tags: javascript

How would I get the numbers on each side of a symbol using Javascript?

Ex. Get `14` and `21` from `extra chars 14 + 21 extra chars` or `extra chars 14+21 extraChars`.

I had an idea for 14 + 21 using `var ary = 'extra chars 14 + 21 extra chars'.split(' ')` and `indexOf('+')+1` and `indexOf('+')-1` but this does not work for `14+21`.

How would I do this so that it would also support multiple symbols?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expressions something like that...

```
var re = /(\d*) *\+ *(\d*)/g; 
var str = 'extra chars 14 + 21 extra chars';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    console.log(m[0]);
    console.log(m[1]);
    console.log(m[2]);
}
```

Comment: I will accept the answer when I can. Thanks for the quick answer!

Answer (score 2):

This is a regex question....

If you're in JavaScript, why not:

```
var rx = /(\d+)[\s+]*(\d+)/;
if (var result = rx.exec(input))
{
    var first = parseInt( result[1] );
    var second = parseInt( result[2] );

    var answer = first + second;
    //do something with answer here
}
```

Comment: To support multiple symbols you would want to change the regex and add a switch statement